# Python list generates duplicates every entry

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need a little python script who ask me 3 questions and makes a .csv file with the list of those 3 answers ( one of them is the same on every line ), it's a little bit complicated to explain but easy to see in example so there's an example:

```
What fruit do you want to purchase ?
- Apples
What color ?
- Red
How many?
- 10
What color ?
- Green
How many?
- 30
```

And the result file should have:

```
Fruit;Color;Qty
Apples;Red;10
Apples;Green;30
```

I've almost done it with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
dataDir = 'Data/Orders/'
class NewOrders:
    def Create(self):
        orderNum = str(raw_input('Introduce order reference: '))
        orderName = 'ORDERS'+orderNum+'.csv'
        fruitType = str(raw_input('What fruit do you want to purchase: '))
        order = open(dataDir+orderName,'wb')
        order.write('Fruit;Color;Qty\n')
        fruitList=[]
        while 1:
            fruitColor=raw_input('What color: ')
            fruitNumber=raw_input('How many: ')
            if fruitColor=='':
                break
            fruitList.append(fruitColor+';'+fruitNumber+';'+fruitType)
            for article in fruitList:
                order.write('%s\n' % article)
Orders = NewOrders()
Orders.Create()
```

But the result file have:

```
Fruit;Color;Qty
Red;30;Apples
Red;30;Apples
Green;10;Apples
```

Each time new lines are introduced it duplicates the previous ones.

Some tip or help will be appreciated.

Thanks to everybody.

Comment: Try to de-indent the last for cycle :)
Right now you are cycling through fruitList every time you append a new element

Comment: unrelated to you question but worth mentionning: `raw_input()` already returns a `str`, you don't need to convert it to a `str` again. You should also close your file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing out `fruitList` *every time you add another entry to it*:

```
while 1:
    fruitColor=raw_input('What color: ')
    fruitNumber=raw_input('How many: ')
    if fruitColor=='':
        break
    fruitList.append(fruitColor+';'+fruitNumber+';'+fruitType)
    for article in fruitList:
        order.write('%s\n' % article)
```

That `for` loop at the end is run each time you add a colour, so it'll write the first entry, then when you add a second one, it'll write the first and second, if you were to add a third, it'll write the first, second and third, etc.

Move the `for` loop *out* of the `while 1:` loop by un-indenting it:

```
while 1:
    fruitColor=raw_input('What color: ')
    fruitNumber=raw_input('How many: ')
    if fruitColor=='':
        break
    fruitList.append(fruitColor+';'+fruitNumber+';'+fruitType)

for article in fruitList:
    order.write('%s\n' % article)
```

Alternatively, don't use a list *at all* and just directly write the string you appended to the file:

```
while 1:
    fruitColor=raw_input('What color: ')
    fruitNumber=raw_input('How many: ')
    if fruitColor=='':
        break
    order.write(fruitColor+';'+fruitNumber+';'+fruitType)
```

You may want to look at the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), this would let you avoid all the `;` concatenations:

```
import csv


orderNum = raw_input('Introduce order reference: ')
fruitType = str(raw_input('What fruit do you want to purchase: '))

with open('ORDERS{}.csv'.format(orderNum), 'wb') as out:
    order = csv.writer(out, delimiter=';')
    order.writerow(['Fruit', 'Color', 'Qty'])
    while True:
        fruitColor = raw_input('What color: ')
        if not fruitColor:
            break
        fruitNumber = raw_input('How many: ')
        order.writerow([fruitColor, fruitNumber, fruitType])
```

Comment: Thanks, :) And nice to see an alternative of my code. Guess it's time to get a break.